# Navigator.pushNamed not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter

i'm developing a Flutter Application. it contain a Tab and inside the TabBarView this is my code

```
body: TabBarView(
       children: <Widget>[
         notifications.Index(),
         Container(
           child: IconButton( onPressed: ()=>Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notification'),icon:
              Icon(Icons.check_circle),),
         ),
       ],
     ),
```

inside the notification.index this is my code

```
class Index extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IndexState createState() => _IndexState();
}

class _IndexState extends State<Index> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
           child: IconButton( onPressed: ()=>Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notification'),icon:
              Icon(Icons.check_circle),),
         ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

this navigation work fine in the TabBarView and it generate the following error in notification.index

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/notification", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
```

if change notification.index file navigation without namedRoute as follow

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=>(Index()),),);},
```

its work fine.
**Please can i know is there anyway to overcome this error without using Navigator.push()? if there is how?**

Comment: I tried your code and it works just fine

Comment: this is my routes. 
`routes: {
      '/notification':(context)=>Show(),
      '/': (context)=>Home()
    },`

Comment: i'm new to flutter. in my case it still not working. i have the same problem in difference place of my app. both of them are i have imported to the page. let me explain. i have create separate AppBar in a file and import it into other file. its work fine. even the Push() method is work fine. problem is occurred only when i try to pushNamed() 
`appBar: AppBarComponent(
            appBar: AppBar(),
          ),`
this is my AppBarComponent 
`
`

Comment: `return AppBar(
      title: Text('Application'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/notification');},
        ),
      ]);,`
this one also not working

Comment: here you have a complete working code: https://pastebin.com/raw/X2qaSkbd

Comment: thank you @pskink i found the error. mistakenly i have wrap my home page in MaterialApp() twice. one in the main() and other in Home again. i remove one and then it work fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Navigator.pushNamed add routes in main dart MaterialApp widget something like this code below otherwise Flutter cannot know where it route

```
    return MaterialApp(

  routes: {
        '/': (ctx) => MyHomePage(),
       "/notification": (ctx) => NotificationScreen(),
      },
)
```

Comment: i have done this. that is why it work in the TabBarView. the problem is same code doesn't work in the notification.index

Comment: Can you try this
Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      '/notification',
)

Answer (score 0):

"Hot-restart" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep the children:  as *const*